# Interact with second tab of SAP GUI script

Tags: python, sap-gui

I'm creating a script and I need to interact with the second sap tab (in red). When I generate a log using the second screen, it continues playing on the first screen (in green). I would like to interact with several tabs at the same time. What do I need to change in the code for this?

Below is a code example obtained by reproducing in the second tab

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "va03"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

[image]

Comment: What you call "tabs" are Sessions in the language of SAP GUI Scripting. In your code, you are accessing only the first session (`Connection.Children(0)`). If you connect to different SAP systems, each connection is called a Connection and contains one or more Sessions. You can loop at all opened [Connections](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiConnection&product=sap_gui_for_windows) and [Sessions](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSession&product=sap_gui_for_windows) with VBA loop `for` and you can query anything. Hopefully someone will post an answer if you need more information.

Comment: Could you send in the responses a snippet of code that works in both tabs?

Comment: To help you start till someone answers, try with `Set session1 = connection.Children(0)` and `Set session2 = connection.Children(1)` then you can play with the 2 sessions at the same time...

Comment: Thank you Sandra, I made it with your support!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this way of cycling through different sessions:

```vb
' Cycle through the open SAP GUI sessions and check which is in the same 
' system running the matching transaction
For il = 0 To application.Connections.Count - 1
    Set W_conn = application.Connections(il + 0)
    For it = 0 To W_conn.Sessions.Count - 1
        Set W_Sess = W_conn.Sessions(it + 0)
        If W_Sess.Info.SystemName = "NPL" Then
            Set objConn = W_conn
            Set objSess = W_Sess
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

For more information about the properties and the methods, look at the documentation:

- [GuiApplication Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiApplication%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)

  - Property `Connections` (alias: `Children`) of type `GuiComponentCollection`
- [GuiConnection Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiConnection%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)

  - Property `Sessions` (alias: `Children`) of type `GuiComponentCollection`
- [GuiSession Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSession%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)

  - Property `Info` of type `GuiSessionInfo`
- [GuiComponentCollection Collection](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiComponentCollection%20Collection&product=sap_gui_for_windows)

  - Method `Item`, property `Count` (NB: indicating `application.Connections(x)` is the same as `application.Connections.Item(x)`
- [GuiSessionInfo Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSessionInfo%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)

  - Properties `SystemName`, `Client`, `User`, `Language`, etc.

Comment: I edited the answer to indicate meaningful names instead of the generic name `Children` and I added a few links to the documentation. Revert back as needed if you don't agree.